# How to use Swift closure in OC

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, closures

In a Swift `UIViewController`, My code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

typealias SayHello = ()->String

@objc class SwiftViewController:UIViewController{

var sayHello:SayHello?

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let helloClosure = sayHello{
        helloClosure()
    }
}}
```

In my OC `UIViewController`, my code:

```
swiftViewController.sayHello = ^(){

    return "Hello block";
};
```

When `Xcode` compile the OC file ,it shows an error:

> Incompatible block pointer types assigning to 'NSString *
>   _Nonnull(^_Nullable)(void)'from 'char *(^)(void)'

Where is the mistake ... (Sorry, I forgot @ before "Hello block" in OC file. It's a careless mistake. Now it works fine. Thank you!)

Comment: Sorry, what you mean by OC?

Comment: I forgot the @ before "Hello block". It's a careless mistake. Thanks for looking at my question.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the `@` before `"Hello block"`, thus you are returning a C-string, and because you didn't explicitly specified the return type for the block, the compiler infers it as `char*`, which is clearly incompatible with `NSString*`.

If you declare the block as `^NSString*(){`, then you'll get an error telling that the return value doesn't match, and even suggest you to add `@`

Comment: Thanks! I found that mistake just now.  It's a careless mistake !